# Cannot install openjdk-8-jre successfully On 18.04

Tags: 18.04

```
pcu29@pcu29:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
[sudo] password for pcu29: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-8-plugin fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-wqy-microhei fonts-wqy-zenhei
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 173 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 100 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'astyle' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more explanation ? Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Answer (score 2):

The file is corrupted. Remove it using:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/astyle.list
```

Then reinstall the package using:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall openjdk-8-jre
```